# Replace exact variable string with variable text in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, string, function

I'm working on a replying system similar to twitters.
In a string there is a piece of text where the id is variable ex.: `14&` , `138&` depending to who you're replying.
How can I find the `14&` in a string and replace it with `<u>14&</u>`?

This is how it looks:

```
14& this is a reply to the comment with id 14
```

This is how it should look like:

```
<u>14&</u> this is a reply to the comment with id 14
```

How can I do this in PHP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: space, any size number & then space - is that correct?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, that's correct. :)

Comment: Do you want it to also replace 3 and 4 in the following, or should those be excluded? `1& in the beginning. 2& in the middle. 3&followed by a word. And4& preceded by a word. Finally ending with a 5&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = "14& this is a reply to the comment with id 14";

var_dump(preg_replace("~\d+&~", '<u>$0</u>', $text));
```

outputs:

```
string '<u>14&</u> this is a reply to the comment with id 14' (length=52)
```

To get rid of the `&`:

```
preg_replace("~(\d+)&~", '<u>$1</u>', $text)
```

outputs:

```
string '<u>14</u> this is a reply to the comment with id 14' (length=51)
```

`$0` or `$1` will be the your id. You can replace the markup with anything you like.

for instance a link:

```
$text = "14& is a reply to the comment with id 14";

var_dump(preg_replace("~(\d+)&~", '<a href="#comment$1">this</a>', $text));
```

outputs:

```
string '<a href="#comment14">this</a> is a reply to the comment with id 14' (length=66)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the ID, it's simple:

```
<?php
  $tweet_id = '14';
  $replaced = str_replace("{$tweet_id}&", "<u>{$tweet_id.}&</u>", $original);
```

If you don't, preg_replace

```
<?php
  //look for 1+ decimals (0-9) ending with '$' and replaced it with
  //original wrapped in <u>
  $replaced = preg_replace('/(\d+&)/', '<u>$1</u>', $original);
```

Comment: I expanded my answer: it uses [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions with the [preg_replace](http://dk.php.net/preg_replace) function.

```
<?php

$str = '14& this is a reply to the comment with id 14';
echo preg_replace('(\d+&)', '<u>$0</u>', $str);
```

The regex matches: one or more digits followed by an ampersand.